# Jangomail Integration with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, integration, email, data-synchronization, mail-server

Has anyone used or uses this feature?  I've been using the free trial of Centerprise recommended to me which works really well in building specific contact lists I want from Salesforce imported into Jangomail.  Is it worth looking into Jangomail's integration with Salesforce because I haven't had the time to figure it out.  I might have to spend the $250 per month after the free trial for Centerprise because it's so easy to use and saves me a lot of time, but I could save this amount if Jangomail can already do this for me.  In other words, can Jangomail's integration with Salesforce scrub the contacts I want from Salesforce to obtain the contacts needed for segment specific eCampaigns?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you just need simple load of data from Salesforce, why should you pay for an integration tool. But, if you want anything more than that, like scrubbing and doing more meaningful stuff with your list, then I would say go for an integration tool. I would recommend sticking to the Centerprise Data Integrator for the reasons you mentioned. It's easy to use and saves a lot of time! Plus it's the least expensive Salesforcfe integration tool in the market - great value for your money.